# Can't connect to wifi after changing the wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless, router

I recently changed my router. The new router has 2g and 5g feature. I configured it with the same name. But there is an awkward situation here. My laptop can't find the 2g but it is working on 5g. Opposite for my mobile. But my laptop finds it on a open guest network which is 2g. After some poking around I found that because the name was changed and the device was not connecting with the newly configured network. I think this is some sort of security options to reduce evil twin attack. Can anyone help me please? It is a TPLink c60 Archer

Comment: What you are saying does not make sense. I have changed my router 3 or 4 times. I always keep the same WiFi name and WiFi password and never had any problems with my laptop or any other device. Check your WiFi password make sure it is the same in the new router. Please edit your question and clarify: You say, *"My laptop can't find the 2g but it is working on 5g."* And then you say, *"But my laptop finds it on a open guest network which is 2g"* Which is correct? Does it work on 2.4GHz or 5GHz or both? If it does not work, add the exact error message.

Comment: @user68186 he named his 2g and 5g WiFi the same. Now he cannot select what WiFi to choose. The device chooses for him to use 2g or 5g. When he enables a guest WiFi the guest WiFi has a unique name and therefore he can distinct it again. Perhaps you should use different WiFi names and check if you can find them. Call one WiFi-2g and the other one WiFi-5g. Sometimes devices have problems to handle the transition to the better WiFi net when both wifis share the same ssid